# Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion

Tags: polynomials

I am not able to understand that how factorisation of f(x) gives the factorisation of f(x-1)
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images as some users cannot view them and they are not searchable on the site. Use [this MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write the Maths out nicely

Comment: Let $p(x)=f(x-1)$.  If  $f(x)=g(x)\times h(x)$ then $p(x)=g(x-1)\times h(x-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: if $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, the polynomial $f_1(x)=f(x-1)$ factors as $g_1(x)h_1(x)$, where
$$g_1(x)=g(x-1), \quad h_1(x)=h(x-1). $$

Conversely, any factorisation of $f_1(x)=g_1(x)h_1(x)$ yields a factorisation of $f(x)$:
$$f(x)=f_1(x+1)=g_1(x+1)h_1(x+1).$$